# 2D Polygon Triangulation

Tags: java, physics, graphics, lwjgl, jbox2d

I am creating a game engine using the JBox2D physics engine. It only allows you to create polygon fixtures up to 8 vertices, To create a body with more than 8 vertices, you need to  create multiple fixtures for the body.

My question is, How can I split the polygons a user creates into smaller polygons for JBox2D?

Also, what topology should I use when splitting the polygons and why?
(If JBox2D can have up to 8 vertices, why not split polygons into 8 per polygon)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation

Comment: I have looked at this, but it didn't explain all...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This simple algorithm assumes you're working with a **convex** polygon (in the case of physics engines you definitely should be):

Loop over the polygon with two indices, one called next and one called last. This is also known as a format called "Triangle Fan". Here's a demo image:

[image]

You set up these two indices and loop something like this:

```
TriVertexList TriangleFan( int vCount, Vec2[] v )
{
  int start = 0;
  int last = 1;
  int prev = 0;
  TriVertexList out;

  while(start != last)
  {
    out.push( v[start], v[last], v[prev] );
    prev = last;
    last = last + 1 == vCount ? 0 : last + 1;
  }

  return out;
}
```

This algorithm can easily be extended to 3D (which I currently use to triangulate my 3D meshes).

Comment: You have the indices labeled `last` and `prev` which is confusing.  Better to call them `cur` and `prev`.

Comment: And this will create artifacts on more complex shapes. Imagine a U or a A. If you always assume that the 0 is the first index to have as your start point your going to get alot of artifacts.

Comment: @Tordin That's why I stated the assumption is a convex polygon.

Comment: Oh, yeah my misstake there. i missed that part :)